# Unable to connect to oracle cloud autonomous database from linux environment

Tags: node.js, linux, oracle, azure-web-app-service, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I am using a Node JS application that has Oracle Autonomous Database as a backend.
It works perfectly on my local machine and I am able to connect it well without any issue.
I tried deploying Node JS project to Azure WebAppService on Linux server.

Initially after deployment I my project was not able to find the Oracle client and so after searching a lot I was able to fix that problem by below

[steps](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html)

with this I was able to solve client issue.
I have wallet files which I received from oracle which I have placed in admin folder

but now the problem is when I make any request I am getting this error

```
data:{"message":"db.doConnect is not a function","stack":"TypeError: 
db.doConnect is not a `function\n`
createPool() callback: ORA-28759: failure to open file
```

my code:
// Include all external dependencies
const oracledb = require('oracledb');
// Intialize variables
const numRows = 100;
let respArr = [];
let connectionObject;
async function initialize(envName) {

```
  await oracledb.createPool({
    user: process.env.DATABASEUSERNAME,
    password: process.env.DATABASEPASSWORD,
    connectString: process.env.DATABASECONNECTIONSTRING,
  });
}

async function close(poolAlias) {
  await oracledb.getPool(poolAlias).close();
}
// Function to iterate through all the rows fetched in the result set and resturn the same
async function fetchRowsFromRS(connection, resultSet, numRows) {
  // Get the rows
  try {
    const rows = await resultSet.getRows(numRows);
    // no rows, or no more rows, then close the result set
    if (rows.length === 0) {
      console.log('No rows returned');
      // doClose(connection, resultSet);
    } else if (rows.length > 0) {
      console.log(`Got ${rows.length} rows`);
      respArr = respArr.concat(rows);
      // Call the function recursively to get more rows
      await fetchRowsFromRS(connection, resultSet, numRows);
    }
    // Return the rows
    return respArr;
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

async function simpleExecute(statement, binds = [], numberOutCur, poolAlias, opts = {}) {
  try {
    await initialize();
    opts.outFormat = oracledb.OBJECT;
    opts.autoCommit = true;
  
    
    connectionObject = await oracledb.getConnection(poolAlias);
    const finalResult = {};
    const result = await connectionObject.execute(statement, binds, opts);
    let promises = [];

    for (let idx = 0; idx < numberOutCur; idx++) {
      const refCurName = `ref_cur_${idx}`;
      promises.push(fetchRowsFromRS(connectionObject, result.outBinds[refCurName], numRows));
      const resultRows = await Promise.all(promises);
      respArr = [];
      finalResult[refCurName] = resultRows;
      promises = [];
    }
    return finalResult;
    // const values = await Promise.all(promises);
    // return values;
  } catch (error) {
    return error;
  } finally {
    if (connectionObject) {
      try {
        await connectionObject.close();
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    }
  }
}

// Function to release the connection
function doRelease(connection) {
  connection.close(
    (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err.message);
      }
    },
  );
}

// Function to close the result set connection
function doClose(connection, resultSet) {
  resultSet.close(
    (err) => {
      if (err) { console.log(err.message); }
      doRelease(connection);
    },
  );
}

// Export functions
module.exports.simpleExecute = simpleExecute;
module.exports.initialize = initialize;
module.exports.close = close;
```

I call my procs using this

```
 const allProducts = await dbSvc.simpleExecute(query, cart_data_binds, 1, 
    'default');
```

what I understood with this message is I am not able to connect to my cloud database and I am not sure how to solve this can anyone help me with it its been 2 weeks now with this problem.

In Node JS project I am using simpleoracle library to connect my oracle cloud anonymous database

Comment: Can you post any of the code that is actually generating the error? It is hard to evaluate the error message without being able to place it in context with what you have done.

Comment: Sounds like something is missing in your deployment. The message isn't really saying it can't connect; rather, that it can't even *try* to connect.  Not sure what 'simpleoracle library' is but it looks like maybe Node can't find that? Showing the code, including how `db` is defined and configured, would be helpful.

Comment: 'ORA-28759: failure to open file' sounds like you didn't update the WALLET_LOCATION directory in sqlnet.ora.  Check the node-oracledb doc on connecting to ADB: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connectionadb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, [Christopher Jones](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4799035/christopher-jones) and [saiharika213](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1109#issuecomment-498595260). Posting your suggestions as an answer to help other community members.

This `ORA-28759: failure to open file` error seems you need to update the `WALLET_LOCATION` directory in `sqlnet.ora`. You can refer to [Connecting to Oracle Cloud Autonomous Databases](https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#connectionadb)

You can resolve this error by changing the connection string to point to the wallet location.
Move the wallets to respective project folder and modify the connection string as below in `dbConfig.js`.
Provide the wallet path from root till wallet folder.

For example:

```
module.exports = {
user: username,
password:password,
connectString:"(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = Hostname )(PORT = XXXX))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = Servicename))(SECURITY=(MY_WALLET_DIRECTORY=/Users/yharika/Node_Projects/invoice_app/config/wallet)))"
}
```

You can refer to [Unable to connect to oracle database from node js using sqlnet.ora with oracle wallet](https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb/issues/1109) and [Connecting with TCPS - ora-28759: failure to open file](https://forums.toadworld.com/t/connecting-with-tcps-ora-28759-failure-to-open-file/47937)

Comment: thanks @DeepDave-MT this gave a major clue what wrong I was doing and finally solve the issue